# C++: corrupted double-linked list and memory corruption

Tags: c++, memory, vector, sdl-2

I know this question has answers in stackoverflow, but still i can't resolv my problem, I don't see the error. I'm using vector and I think I'm using it correctly, I'm not doing any free or malloc/calloc or something. However, I'm sure the problem comes with vector, doing something wrong.
The most strange part is debbuging the program, it ocurrs in two or three differents sites.

I compile the code with SDL2 and the default gcc on linux. I'm using Netbeans, using the command

```
g++ -std=c++11 -g -Wall   -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "path/src/game/Game.o.d" -o path/src/game/Game.o src/game/Game.cpp
```

and linking with -lSDL2 -lSDL2_image

The error, one of this

```
malloc(): memory corruption (fast): 0x0000000000d86d50 ***
corrupted double-linked list: 0x00000000013fb5d0 ***
```

or less usual: [link][1]

Valgrind show something like this but I don't know how to use it: [link][2]

I put here the most important code, but I leave you the complete project to see if you want. Hope you can help me. I'm not sure if I'm doing something wrong or the problem come on other way.

[Link to project][3]

Main.cpp

```
#include ... //some includes
using namespace std;

Shape* shape;
TableBoard board;
Square* square;
Command* command;

void keyDown(SDL_Event &evento) {
    if (evento.type == SDL_KEYDOWN) {
    SDL_Keycode key = evento.key.keysym.sym;
    command = nullptr;
    switch (key) {
        case SDLK_LEFT:
        command = new LeftRight(board, *shape, Direction::LEFT);
        shape->addCommand(command);
        break;

        case SDLK_RIGHT:
        command = new LeftRight(board, *shape, Direction::RIGHT);
        shape->addCommand(command);
        break;

        case SDLK_DOWN:
        command = new FallToGround(board, *shape);
        shape->addCommand(command);
        break;

        case SDLK_ESCAPE:
        exit(0);

    }
    }
}

void newShape() {
    if (shape == nullptr || !shape->isCanFall()) {
    shape = new LShape(*square);
    board.addShape(shape);
    shape->setCanFall(true);

    Command* command = new Fall(board, *shape);
    shape->addCommand(command);
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    Window pantalla;

    SDL_Event evento;
    board = TableBoard(pantalla.getWindow(), 20, 10);
    Board meassureBoard = board.getMeassureBoard();


    SDL_Texture* image = IMG_LoadTexture(pantalla.getPantalla(),
        "resources/images/blue_bold.png");

    //creo una celda, le paso datos de table y que él se pinte
    square = new Square();
    square = new Square();
    square->setGraphics(meassureBoard, image);
    square->setX(3);
    square->setY(1);


    bool letsQuit = false;
    Timer timer{};
    timer.start();
    newShape();
    while (!letsQuit) {
    pantalla.clear();
    shape->executeCommands();
    shape->clearCommandsFinished();

    board.paint(pantalla.getPantalla());
    board.drawLines(pantalla.getPantalla());
    pantalla.actualizar();

    while (SDL_PollEvent(&evento)) {
        if (evento.type == SDL_QUIT) { // Si es de salida
        letsQuit = true;
        } else {
        keyDown(evento);
        }
    }

    newShape();

    if (timer.delta() < 16) {
        SDL_Delay(16 - timer.delta());
    }
    timer.restart();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Part of Shape (parent class of LShape)

```
void Shape::executeCommands() {
    for(vector<Command*>::iterator it = commands.begin(); it != commands.end(); ++it) {
    (*it)->execute();
    }
}

void Shape::clearCommandsFinished() {
    vector<int> remove;
    int index=0;
    for(vector<Command*>::iterator it = commands.begin(); it != commands.end(); ++it) {
    if ((*it)->isAlive() != true) {
        remove.push_back(index);
    }
    index++;
    }

    for(vector<int>::iterator it = remove.begin(); it != remove.end(); ++it) {
        commands.erase(commands.begin()+(*it));
    }
}
```

Part of command Fall, left and right is similar. Here gives the error

```
void Fall::execute() {
    if (isAlive() && timer.delta() >= milisecondsFalling) {
    timer.restart();
    bool canMove = true;
    vector<Square> squares = shape->nextMove(0, 1);

    if (shape->isCanFall()) {
        int number=shape->getNUMBER_OF_SQUARES();
        for (int i = 0; i < number && canMove; i++) {
        //check the range
        if (squares[i].getX() < 0
            || squares[i].getX() > board.getNumberColumns() - 1
            || squares[i].getY() < 0
            || squares[i].getY() > board.getNumberRows() - 1) {

            canMove = false;

        } else {
            if (board.isFilled(shape, squares[i])) {
            canMove = false;
            }
        }
        }

        //if we can move, move it definitively
        if (canMove) {
        shape->move(0, 1);
        board.updateBoard();
        }else{
        shape->setCanFall(false);
        }
    } else {
        alive = false;
    } //-> AT THIS EXACTLY MOMENT GIVE THE ERROR!! NOT AFTER, NOT BEFORE

    }
}
```

Not important, but gives error here too. Parts of the window class

```
void Window::actualizar() {
    // Mostramos la pantalla
    SDL_RenderPresent(renderer); //EXACTLY POINT WHERE THROW THE ERROR, less frecuent
}

void Window::inicializacion() {
    if (SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_VIDEO) < 0) {
    cout << "No se pudo iniciar SDL: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    exit(1);
    }

    atexit(SDL_Quit);

    pantalla = SDL_CreateWindow("Tetris",   //CREATED AS PRIVATE IN HEADER INSIDE CLASS: SDL_Window *pantalla;
              SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
              SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
              window.w, window.h,
              0);

    renderer = SDL_CreateRenderer(pantalla, -1, SDL_RENDERER_ACCELERATED);

    this->clear();

    if (pantalla == NULL) {
    cout << "Error iniciando el entorno gráfico: " << SDL_GetError() << endl;
    exit(1);
    }

    this->pantalla=pantalla;
}

Window::Window() {
    window.w=1024;
    window.h= 768;

    inicializacion();
}
```

Edit: links deleted. Problem solved

Comment: 1) What was the last change you made before the error appeared, and 2) are you familiar with the idea of a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: If the error/s appear when void Fall::execute() returns, it strongly suggests stack corruption before that point.

Comment: I suspect that you will have to do some more debugging yourself before anyone here will try to climb your wall of code.  Comment out some calls, cut stuff out, make the error go away.

Comment: @Beta, I know about the minimal complete example, and also I know I didn't do it here. I was unable to get less code with the error due to the random of the errors. Hope next time I ask better :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm *not* going to debug this entire thing (which would be utterly non productive for either of us). I took a **brief** look at your source base, and spotted this:

```
vector<Square> Shape::nextMove(int x, int y) 
{
    //make a copy to not really moving the squares
    vector<Square> clone(numberSquares);
    for (int i = 0; i <= numberSquares; i++) { // <<=== HERE
        clone[i] = *(new Square(squares[i]));
    }
    //get the next move
    moveShape(clone, x, y);
    //return the modified squares
    return clone;
}
```

That `<=` is indexing one-past the size of your source and destination vectors, which is BAD. Making matters worse, the code within the for-loop is a blatant memory leak. The entire function should be reduced to this:

```
vector<Square> Shape::nextMove(int x, int y) 
{
    vector<Square> clone = squares;
    moveShape(clone, x, y);
    return clone;
}
```

Best of luck

Comment: My intention never was none of you debugging my code, sorry for the misunderstanding. All I wanted is the brief look you and @Martin James did. Both of you are right, that was the problem and now seems solved.